# Lottery probability of winning

Tags: probability, probability-theory

On a certain day, $N$ lottery ticket are sold and $M$ win. To have a probability of at least $\alpha$ of winning on that day, approximately how many ticket should he purchased?

The answer is the least integer greater than $- \frac{M}{N} \log(1-\alpha)$ but I don't know why

Comment: If I need $ \alpha = 1$, the answer should be N-M+1 but the model answer is infinity

Comment: Also, as $M$ gets bigger - as more tickets win - this formula suggests that you need to buy more tickets to get the same chance of winning?

Answer (score 2):

Hm....how are you approximating this answer? If we assume that each ticket has an equal chance of winning (which is maybe not accurate - if $N$ and $M$ are fixed, we should be using a hypergeometric RV), then I get the following:

Each ticket that you buy has a probability of losing of $\frac{N-M}{N}$. So if you buy $x$ tickets, the probability of them all losing is $(\frac{N-M}{N})^{x}$. So your probability of winning is $1 - (\frac{N-M}{N})^{x}$. Then we want: $$1 - (\frac{N-M}{N})^{x} \geq \alpha $$ $$ 1-\alpha \geq (\frac{N-M}{N})^{x} $$ $$ \frac{\ln(1-\alpha)}{\ln(\frac{N-M}{N})} \leq x.$$ (Notice that the inequality flips in that last line since $\frac{N-M}{N} < 1$, so its natural log is negative.)

Now, using the power series $\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \ldots $, we can say that $\ln(\frac{N-M}{N}) = \ln(1 + \frac{-M}{N})$, which is thus about $-M/N$. But then I get $x \geq \frac{-N}{M}\ ln(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: Actually, this answer is found in a textbook but I don't know why

Comment: Which book? Any chance you can scan the relevant pages?

Comment: @user134927, I think the book has a typo the answer coolpapa derived is correct I think.

Comment: @coolpapa, the distribution is  geometric with probability (M/N) of winning and 1-(M/N) of not winning.  I you sum till 1 to x, it is $1-(\frac{N-M}{N})^x$. and then you get the remainder of the result.  Let me know if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the same as the reasoning I used, I think.